# Type error with function on queryset

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a function to convert currency. But I keep getting an error.

> Type error- string indices must be integers, not str

Can anyone assist?

Traceback ([here](http://dpaste.com/1CYXDR9))

```
def exchange(price, current, target):
    try:
        price *= Exchangerate.objects.get(basecurrency=current, targetcurrency=target).exchangerate
    except Exception:
        pass
    return price

def symbol(symbol):
    try:
        symbol = Currency.objects.get(symbol=symbol).symbol
    except Exception:
        print
    return symbol
```

..............

```
class ProductItemView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            pk = int(kwargs['pk'])
        except Exception:
            return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        result = (
            Product.objects
            .filter(pk=pk)
            .values('pk', 'name',)
            .annotate(
                currency=F('variation__price__currency'),
                currencycode=F('variation__price__currency__currencycode'),
                symbol=F('variation__price__currency__symbol'),
                price=F('variation__price__price'),
            )
            .order_by('variation__price__created')
        ).first()

        img = Image.objects.filter(variation__product=pk).all().values('image')
        result['image'] = list(set(i["image"] for i in img))

        for i in result:
            i['price'] = str(i['price']) + ' (Estimate: ' + (symbol(user.settings_currency.symbol)) + ' ' + "{:.2f}".format((exchange(i['price'], i['currency'], user.settings_currency.id,))) + ' )'
        del i['price']

        return Response(result)
```

Comment: Can you print what is in result? most likely you cant' loop a list with 'price' as index.

Comment: Where do I put the print and how do I write it?

Comment: How are you running your Django?

Comment: if you put the full stacktrace this is easy to solve

Comment: Unrelated, but `except Exception: pass` is one of the worst things you can write in Python.

Answer (score 1):

So, I don't know anything about your Product object, so here goes my ideas based on the options I see.

1) It could be that result is a string, not a dict, since it seems you are assigning what looks like the first element of an iterable object to it. If this is the case, check what Product.object(...).first() actually returns.

2) It is possible that you wanted to get a list/tuple of dictionaries. In that case, do not choose .first() from Product.objects(..). Then it would make sense to iterate that list of dictionaries with "for i in result:" etc.

3) If you did intend to get the first member of the Product.object(..) tuple, then your for loop actually loops the items of this dictionary. It is very possible that i then becomes a string, which you can only use integer indices for. This will then throw the exception you saw. To fix, remove the for loop.

It appears to me that result is a dictionary, since the assignment to result['image'] seems to work fine. In that case, my item 3) applies to your situation. However, I am not sure whether that is the behavior you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Your stacktrace shows that the error is here:

```
i['price'] = str(i['price']) + ' (Estimate: ' +     
             (symbol(user.settings_currency.symbol)) + 
             ' ' + "{:.2f}".format((exchange(i['price'], i['currency'], 
             user.settings_currency.id,))) + ' )'
```

Here you are trying `i` as a dictionary. You can use i['somestring'] notation only for dictionaries. But python is telling you that you cannot use it with `i` because it's a string! That's basically what is meant by

> Exception Value: string indices must be integers, not str

At any rate, `i` is not a dictionary says python. But how can that be? Pretty hard to figure out isn't it. What if your code was simpler? In fact it can be.

```
    result = Product.objects
        .filter(pk=pk)
        .values('pk', 'name',)
        .annotate(
            currency=F('variation__price__currency'),
            currencycode=F('variation__price__currency__currencycode'),
            symbol=F('variation__price__currency__symbol'),
            price=F('variation__price__price'),
        )
        .order_by('variation__price__created')[0]


    img = Image.objects.filter(variation__product=pk).all().values('image')
    result['image'] = list(set(i["image"] for i in img))

    result['price'] = str(result['price']) + ' (Estimate: ' + (symbol(user.settings_currency.symbol)) + ' ' + "{:.2f}".format((exchange(result['price'], result['currency'], user.settings_currency.id,))) + ' )'

    return Response(result)
```

Do let me know if the error persists.

Comment: Thanks but this gives me a name error (global name 'i' is not defined). Can you please adjust your code to define the 'i"?

Comment: Sorry didn't run the code (can't since I don't have the dependencies). Updating answer i should be replaced with result

Comment: Thanks- I now get an error saying 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'symbol'. (http://dpaste.com/0VA755J). Elsewhere in my app- I have used this which works correctly `i['price'] = str(i['price']) + ' ' +  '(' + (symbol(user.settings_currency.symbol)) + "{:.2f}".format((exchange(i['price'], i['currency'], user.settings_currency.id,))) + ')'` However- I cannot get this code to work in this example

Comment: Your code above products that error. The code in my example in the comment just above is one I use elsewhere successfully (to show an example).

Comment: Excuse me you posted your code because it was producing an error so what's this about successfully using that code?

Comment: Also that particular error you mention in the comments can only come from ehre user.settings_currency.symbol and i have no idea what that can be caused by because you haven't said what user is in your original question